# How to run bat file from java with arguments (i.e file name with full path) having folder name with space

Tags: java, process, runtime

Am trying to execute the a bat file with some arguments through a JAVA programmes . the arguments are file name with full path, And this path had some folder name with space, which are creating issue and giving me the following error

> Error: 'D:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command

the code is as below

```
String command = "D:\Documents and Settings\ A.bat" + " " D:\Documents and Settings\B.xml



 1. process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe","/c",command});
 2. process.waitFor();
 3. exitValue = process.exitValue();
```

Comment: have you tried with double slashes? String command = "D:\\Documents and Settings\\ A.bat" + " " D:\\Documents and Settings\\B.xml

Comment: *"the code is as below"* At best, that is pseudo-code.  In any case, to answer your next 3 (to 5) questions, read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Comment: i had already tried this option, but no luck

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `\` in your string (i.e. doubling them: `D:\\Documents`), but that is not the problem. You can try to escape the spaces `Documents\\ and\\ Settings` or you use the [exec method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) that does this for you. Just dont build the command line by yourself. Better use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for starting processes.

Comment: could you please tell me some details, am getting the command i.e. string object directly from the program.i want to know how can i do it from processbuilder

Answer (score 0):

```
String command = "\"D:\Documents and Settings\\" A.bat" + " \"D:\Documents and Settings\B.xml\""
```

Escape double quotes, so you can include double quotes in the literal, to give:

```
cmd.exe /x "D:\Documents and Settings\" A.bat "D:\Documents and Settings\B.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing. I googled whole day but didn't make it work. At Last I handled it in this way, I am sharing it if it comes to any use of anybody :

```
        String command = "A.bat D:\\Documents and Settings\\B.xml";
        File commandDir = new File ( "D:\\Documents and Settings ");        
        String[] cmdArray = { "cmd.exe", "/c", command };


        1. Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmdArray, null, cmdArray );
        2. process.waitFor();
        3. exitValue = process.exitValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a while searching on SO and the wider Internet and was about to post this as a new question when I came across this, which does seem identical to my issue...

I am trying to call a Windows batch file from Java. The batch file takes several arguments but just the first, which is a path to a data file, is of relevance to this problem. The cut-down command line that I have been experimenting with is essentially:

```
cmd /c c:\path\to\my\batchfile.bat c:\path\to\my\datafile.mdl
```

I'm using Apache Commons Exec which ultimately delegates to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)`, the 'correct' version as opposed to the overloaded versions taking a single `String` command. Quoting of the arguments when they contain spaces is therefore taken care of.

Now, both the path to the batch file and/or the path to the data file can have spaces in them. If *either* the path to the batch file *or* the path to the data file have spaces in, then the batch file is executed. But if *both* have spaces in them then the path to the batch file is truncated at the first space.

This has to be a (Java or Windows?) bug, right? I've debugged right down to the native call to `create()` in `java.lang.ProcessImpl` and all seems ok. I'm on JDK1.6.